# JavaScript append array to array from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the below Table TDs that I need to get the values.

```
     <table style="border: 1px solid blue;margin: 15px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="drdsclient">DSCDS201020101</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Maximum online generations:</td>
            <td id="drcheckval" class="notopborder">30</td>
            <td id="drchecknotes" class="notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Retention Rule set:</td>
            <td id="drcheckval" class="notopborder">No default Retention rule set</td>
            <td id="drchecknotes" class="notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Backup Schedule set:</td>
            <td id="drcheckval" class="notopborder">No default Schedule set</td>
            <td id="drchecknotes" class="notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td class="drdsclient">DSCDS901999102</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Maximum online generations:</td>
            <td id="drcheckval"  class="notopborder">29</td>
            <td id="drchecknotes" class="notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Retention Rule set:</td>
            <td id="drcheckval"  class="notopborder">30 days</td>
            <td id="drchecknotes" class="notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Backup Schedule set:</td>
            <td id="drcheckval"  class="notopborder">Monday to Friday @ 21:00</td>
            <td id="drchecknotes" class="notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I keep using IDs and Classes with the below JS code:

```
    var array1 = [];
        $(' .drdsclient ').each(function(){
            var obj = { 
                drdsc: $(" .drdsclient ").text(),
                drcheck1: $(" #drcheck1 " ).text(),
                drcheckval1: $(" #drcheckval1 ").text(),
                drchecknotes1: $(" #drchecknotes1 ").text(),
                drcheck2: $(" #drcheck2 " ).text(),
                drcheckval2: $(" #drcheckval2 ").text(),
                drchecknotes2: $(" #drchecknotes2 ").text(),
                drcheck3: $(" #drcheck3 " ).text(),
                drcheckval3: $(" #drcheckval3 ").text(),
                drchecknotes3: $(" #drchecknotes3 ").text()
            };
            var arr2 = array1.push(obj);
        });
```

But instead of appending to the array, it doubles the values and I get the below result:

```
[0]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS201020101DSCDS901999102"
    [drcheck1] => "Maximum online generations:Maximum online generations:"
    [drcheckval1] => "30999"
    [drchecknotes1] => "notesnotes"
    [drcheck2] => "Default Retention Rule set:Default Retention Rule set:"
    [drcheckval2] => "No default Retention rule set30 days"
    [drchecknotes2] => "notesnotes"
    [drcheck3] => "Default Backup Schedule set:Default Backup Schedule set:"
    [drcheckval3] => "No default Schedule setMonday to Friday @ 21:00"
    [drchecknotes3] => "notesnotes"
[1]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS201020101DSCDS901999102"
    [drcheck1] => "Maximum online generations:Maximum online generations:"
    [drcheckval1] => "30999"
    [drchecknotes1] => "notesnotes"
    [drcheck2] => "Default Retention Rule set:Default Retention Rule set:"
    [drcheckval2] => "No default Retention rule set30 days"
    [drchecknotes2] => "notesnotes"
    [drcheck3] => "Default Backup Schedule set:Default Backup Schedule set:"
    [drcheckval3] => "No default Schedule setMonday to Friday @ 21:00"
    [drchecknotes3] => "notesnotes"
```

Any way I can get an array like the below?

```
[0]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS201020101"
    [drcheck1] => Maximum online generations:"
    [drcheckval1] => "30"
    [drchecknotes1] => "notes"
    [drcheck2] => "Default Retention Rule set:"
    [drcheckval2] => "No default Retention rule set"
    [drchecknotes2] => "notes"
    [drcheck3] => "Default Backup Schedule set:"
    [drcheckval3] => "No default Schedule set"
    [drchecknotes3] => "notes"
[1]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS901999102"
    [drcheck1] => "Maximum online generations:"
    [drcheckval1] => "999"
    [drchecknotes1] => "notes"
    [drcheck2] => "Default Retention Rule set:"
    [drcheckval2] => "30 days"
    [drchecknotes2] => "notes"
    [drcheck3] => "Default Backup Schedule set:"
    [drcheckval3] => "Monday to Friday @ 21:00"
    [drchecknotes3] => "notes"
```

Comment: First off, id must be unique val in the html, it is bad practice to have same id on elements.

Comment: obj = [{ "abc":$("#something").text()},...] and then array1 += obj;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few issues in your code. First you've repeated the same `id` attribute in multiple places which is invalid. You need to change them to classes. Secondly in the JS code you're trying to read `id` that don't exist. It seems you're getting confused between `id` and the index of the element.

To actually achieve what you need you'll need to loop through the `.drdsclient` elements and retrieve all the following `tr` elements until the next `.drdsclient`. From there you can loop over those rows and build the object as required, like this:

```js
var array1 = $('.drdsclient').map(function() {
  var $client = $(this);
  var $rows = $client.closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.drdsclient)');
  var obj = {
    drdsc: $client.text()
  };
  
  $rows.each(function(i) { 
    var rowNum = i + 1;
    obj['drcheck' + rowNum] = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    obj['drcheckval' + rowNum] = $(this).find('td.drcheckval').text();
    obj['drchecknotes' + rowNum] = $(this).find('td.drchecknotes').text();
  });
  
  return obj;
}).get();

console.log(array1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border: 1px solid blue;margin: 15px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="drdsclient">DSCDS201020101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="drcheck">
    <td>Maximum online generations:</td>
    <td class="drcheckval notopborder">30</td>
    <td class="drchecknotes notopborder">notes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="drcheck">
    <td>Default Retention Rule set:</td>
    <td class="drcheckval notopborder">No default Retention rule set</td>
    <td class="drchecknotes notopborder">notes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="drcheck">
    <td>Default Backup Schedule set:</td>
    <td class="drcheckval notopborder">No default Schedule set</td>
    <td class="drchecknotes notopborder">notes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="drcheck">
    <td class="drdsclient">DSCDS901999102</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="drcheck">
    <td>Maximum online generations:</td>
    <td class="drcheckval notopborder">29</td>
    <td class="drchecknotes notopborder">notes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="drcheck">
    <td>Default Retention Rule set:</td>
    <td class="drcheckval notopborder">30 days</td>
    <td class="drchecknotes notopborder">notes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="drcheck">
    <td>Default Backup Schedule set:</td>
    <td class="drcheckval notopborder">Monday to Friday @ 21:00</td>
    <td class="drchecknotes notopborder">notes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also note that having incremental object properties isn't a very good idea. A better solution would be to build arrays of the values and place those in the properties of the object. This makes looping over the result much simpler.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Comment: Just realized that I need to loop through this array later on. Is there a way of just having drcheck instead of drcheck1, 2 and so on?

Comment: Yes - you'd need to build three separate arrays as I mentioned at the end of my answer. If you have issues with that I'd suggest you start a new question about it